# How to ask questions to user using Dialog.ElicitSlot using c#?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Right now I am getting error "The following directive does not supported: ElicitSlotDirective", while I trying to ask question using ResponseBuilder.DialogElicitSlot of Alexa.Net nuget library.

How can I fix this?, Thanks in advance?